# infinite scrolling using jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

The script is working fine, but when the content ends, the page never reaches to the end. I need to make it stop infinite scrolling when the loaded content is end.

Another question, i dont want to load all the divs right away, i need to load it every five in five, how can i do that?

js:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
```

html:

```
<div id="postswrapper">
   <div class="item">content</div>
   ...
   <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="bigLoader.gif" /></center></div>
</div>
```

and the loadmore.php contains many `<div class="item">content</div>`

Comment: when you call this function.?

Comment: i call it on the index file (not external js). its inside a `$(function(){....})`

Comment: if you check value for both $(window).scrollTop() & $(document).height() - $(window).height() its will always says 0...i tested i dont know how you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm making 2 assumptions here first that you're calling the code you provided using the [scroll listener](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). Second you might want to call the same code later.

To stop it you need to create a flag so it stop making the calls (or unbind the scroll if you dont want to use the same later), to paginate your results you need to create a variable that count the page you're actually showing but also you need to modify the code processing the ajax request so it uses the page data we're sending.

```
flag = true; //Flag to identify if the code should request more results
page = 1;    //Current page 
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if(flag && ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()))
            {
            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
            $.ajax({
            url: "loadmore.php",
        data: {page:page}
            success: function(html)
            {
               if(html)
               {
                   $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                   $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                   page++; 
               }else
               {
                   flag = false;
                   $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
              }
            }
        });
    }
});
```